# How to output CDATA using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml

I've discovered that cElementTree is about 30 times faster than `xml.dom.minidom` and I'm rewriting my XML encoding/decoding code. However, I need to output XML that contains CDATA sections and there doesn't seem to be a way to do that with ElementTree.

Can it be done?

Comment: > I need to output XML that contains CDATA sections 

Why? It seems a strange requirment.

Comment: It's a requirement I have - chunks of CDATA are sometimes much more human-readable.

Comment: @bortzmeyer It's useful for adding HTML to KML (Google Maps XML files).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After a bit of work, I found the answer myself. Looking at the ElementTree.py source code, I found there was special handling of XML comments and preprocessing instructions. What they do is create a factory function for the special element type that uses a special (non-string) tag value to differentiate it from regular elements.

```
def Comment(text=None):
    element = Element(Comment)
    element.text = text
    return element
```

Then in the `_write` function of ElementTree that actually outputs the XML, there's a special case handling for comments:

```
if tag is Comment:
    file.write("<!-- %s -->" % _escape_cdata(node.text, encoding))
```

In order to support CDATA sections, I create a factory function called `CDATA`, extended the ElementTree class and changed the `_write` function to handle the CDATA elements.

This still doesn't help if you want to parse an XML with CDATA sections and then output it again with the CDATA sections, but it at least allows you to create XMLs with CDATA sections programmatically, which is what I needed to do.

The implementation seems to work with both ElementTree and cElementTree.

```
import elementtree.ElementTree as etree
#~ import cElementTree as etree

def CDATA(text=None):
    element = etree.Element(CDATA)
    element.text = text
    return element

class ElementTreeCDATA(etree.ElementTree):
    def _write(self, file, node, encoding, namespaces):
        if node.tag is CDATA:
            text = node.text.encode(encoding)
            file.write("\n<![CDATA[%s]]>\n" % text)
        else:
            etree.ElementTree._write(self, file, node, encoding, namespaces)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    text = """
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <text>
    This is just some sample text.
    </text>
    """

    e = etree.Element("data")
    cdata = CDATA(text)
    e.append(cdata)
    et = ElementTreeCDATA(e)
    et.write(sys.stdout, "utf-8")
```

Comment: This does not seem possible anymore since the _write method is not there, and the _serialize_* functions are static

Comment: What should I do since I can't use _write? So that means I can't use xml.elementtree? This is terrible.

Comment: Thsio reciep won't work for Python 2.7 or 3.2 (and 3.3) - check @amaury's answer bellow. BAsically, teh new ElementTree does not have a "_write" method that can be overriden anymore.

Comment: There is a CDATA element for etree you can use directly.
http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.CDATA-class.html

Answer (score 21):

[lxml](http://lxml.de/) has support for [CDATA](http://lxml.de/api.html#cdata) and API like ElementTree.

Comment: This is huge from the "don't roll your own XML parser" perspective.

Comment: @iny I think your lxml link is broken.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a variant of gooli's solution that works for python 3.2:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

def CDATA(text=None):
    element = etree.Element('![CDATA[')
    element.text = text
    return element

etree._original_serialize_xml = etree._serialize_xml
def _serialize_xml(write, elem, qnames, namespaces):
    if elem.tag == '![CDATA[':
        write("\n<%s%s]]>\n" % (
                elem.tag, elem.text))
        return
    return etree._original_serialize_xml(
        write, elem, qnames, namespaces)
etree._serialize_xml = etree._serialize['xml'] = _serialize_xml


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    text = """
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <text>
    This is just some sample text.
    </text>
    """

    e = etree.Element("data")
    cdata = CDATA(text)
    e.append(cdata)
    et = etree.ElementTree(e)
    et.write(sys.stdout.buffer.raw, "utf-8")
```

Comment: This shoudl work fro Python 2.7 as well  - as the original recipe does not. I jsut came up with another thing that is mode complicated than this.

Comment: This needs updating to add the coding kwarg to the `_serialize_xml` def

Comment: for python 2.7 add an encoding arg to the serialize signature.  

change  `def _serialize_xml(write, elem, qnames, namespaces):`  
to  `def _serialize_xml(write, elem, encoding, qnames, namespaces):`  

change  `write, elem, qnames, namespaces)`  
to  `write, elem, encoding, qnames, namespaces)`  

change  `et.write(sys.stdout.buffer.raw, "utf-8")`  
to  `et.write(sys.stdout, "utf-8")`

Answer (score 12):

**Solution:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree

def CDATA(text=None):
    element = ElementTree.Element('![CDATA[')
    element.text = text
    return element

ElementTree._original_serialize_xml = ElementTree._serialize_xml
def _serialize_xml(write, elem, qnames, namespaces,short_empty_elements, **kwargs):
    if elem.tag == '![CDATA[':
        write("\n<{}{}]]>\n".format(elem.tag, elem.text))
        if elem.tail:
            write(_escape_cdata(elem.tail))
    else:
        return ElementTree._original_serialize_xml(write, elem, qnames, namespaces,short_empty_elements, **kwargs)

ElementTree._serialize_xml = ElementTree._serialize['xml'] = _serialize_xml

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

text = """
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<text>
This is just some sample text.
</text>
"""

e = ElementTree.Element("data")
cdata = CDATA(text)
root.append(cdata)
```

**Background:**

I don't know whether previous versions of proposed code worked very well and whether ElementTree module has been updated but I have faced problems with using this trick:

```
etree._original_serialize_xml = etree._serialize_xml
def _serialize_xml(write, elem, qnames, namespaces):
    if elem.tag == '![CDATA[':
        write("\n<%s%s]]>\n" % (
                elem.tag, elem.text))
        return
    return etree._original_serialize_xml(
        write, elem, qnames, namespaces)
etree._serialize_xml = etree._serialize['xml'] = _serialize_xml
```

The problem with this approach is that after passing this exception, serializer is again treating it as normal tag afterwards. I was getting something like:

```
<textContent>
<![CDATA[this was the code I wanted to put inside of CDATA]]>
<![CDATA[>this was the code I wanted to put inside of CDATA</![CDATA[>
</textContent>
```

And of course we know that will cause only plenty of errors. 
Why that was happening though?

The answer is in this little guy:

```
return etree._original_serialize_xml(write, elem, qnames, namespaces)
```

We don't want to examine code once again through original serialise function if we have trapped our CDATA and successfully passed it through.
Therefore in the "if" block we have to return original serialize function only when CDATA was not there. We were missing "else" before returning original function.

Moreover in my version ElementTree module, serialize function was desperately asking for "short_empty_element" argument. So the most recent version I would recommend looks like this(also with "tail"):

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml import etree

#in order to test it you have to create testing.xml file in the folder with the script
xmlParsedWithET = ElementTree.parse("testing.xml")
root = xmlParsedWithET.getroot()

def CDATA(text=None):
    element = ElementTree.Element('![CDATA[')
    element.text = text
    return element

ElementTree._original_serialize_xml = ElementTree._serialize_xml

def _serialize_xml(write, elem, qnames, namespaces,short_empty_elements, **kwargs):

    if elem.tag == '![CDATA[':
        write("\n<{}{}]]>\n".format(elem.tag, elem.text))
        if elem.tail:
            write(_escape_cdata(elem.tail))
    else:
        return ElementTree._original_serialize_xml(write, elem, qnames, namespaces,short_empty_elements, **kwargs)

ElementTree._serialize_xml = ElementTree._serialize['xml'] = _serialize_xml


text = """
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<text>
This is just some sample text.
</text>
"""
e = ElementTree.Element("data")
cdata = CDATA(text)
root.append(cdata)

#tests
print(root)
print(root.getchildren()[0])
print(root.getchildren()[0].text + "\n\nyay!")
```

The output I got was:

```
<Element 'Database' at 0x10062e228>
<Element '![CDATA[' at 0x1021cc9a8>

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<text>
This is just some sample text.
</text>


yay!
```

I wish you the same result!

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works great for me in Python 3.4.3, and it's really interesting that you only posted it yesterday, and I need it today. Haven't tested in 3.5, but I guess it will break sooner or later still, probably in the next version. Sigh.

Comment: You are welcome. Please keep in mind that always while using ElementTree.parse, you will display only CDATA content (without cdata tag). In my code: 'xmlParsedWithET = ElementTree.parse("testing.xml")'. I figured out how by modifying the code just a little, using lxml you can preserve our precious cdata tags. Let me know if you are interested in that or only standard libs are ok for you

Comment: I was writing a generator for my blog and had to assemble an Atom 1.0 feed. This is kind of a one-off task (if it breaks in the future, I can always use a 3.4 virtualenv), so a hack on STL is acceptable to me.

Comment: Thanks! Works well for python 3.6!

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible AFAIK... which is a pity.  Basically, ElementTree modules assume that the reader is 100% XML compliant, so it shouldn't matter if they output a section as CDATA or some other format that generates the equivalent text.

See [this thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20141015120050/https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2005-June/304602.html) on the Python mailing list for more info.  Basically, they recommend some kind of DOM-based XML library instead.

Comment: I would not call it "a pity". For the XML infoset (the content), there is no difference between "<![CDATA[ & ]]>" and "&amp;"... Most XML parsers won't even let you know what was in the original document.

Comment: That's true, but some data can be dumped and parsed much more efficiently in CDATA format.  So it's a pain to not be able to tell an XML library to handle it in this way.

Comment: The link seems like not available now.

Comment: Thanks. Replaced with Wayback Machine link.

Answer (score 6):

Actually this code has a bug, since you don't catch `]]>` appearing in the data you are inserting as CDATA

as per [Is there a way to escape a CDATA end token in xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223652/is-there-a-way-to-escape-a-cdata-end-token-in-xml)

you should break it into two CDATA's in that case, splitting the `]]>` between the two.

basically `data = data.replace("]]>", "]]]]><![CDATA[>")`
(not necessarily correct, please verify)

Answer (score 6):

You can override ElementTree `_escape_cdata` function:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def _escape_cdata(text, encoding):
    try:
        if "&" in text:
            text = text.replace("&", "&amp;")
        # if "<" in text:
            # text = text.replace("<", "&lt;")
        # if ">" in text:
            # text = text.replace(">", "&gt;")
        return text
    except TypeError:
        raise TypeError(
            "cannot serialize %r (type %s)" % (text, type(text).__name__)
        )

ET._escape_cdata = _escape_cdata
```

Note that you may not need pass extra `encoding` param, depending on your library/python version.

Now you can write CDATA into `obj.text` like:

```py
root = ET.Element('root')
body = ET.SubElement(root, 'body')
body.text = '<![CDATA[perform extra angle brackets escape for this text]]>'
print(ET.tostring(root))
```

and get clear CDATA node:

```xml
<root>
    <body>
        <![CDATA[perform extra angle brackets escape for this text]]>
    </body>
</root>
```

Comment: How exactly do I use this to output CDATA sections? What is "contrib version"?

Comment: @mzjn thanks, edited. You can use it like usually do with inserting text to ET object. I mean `obj.text='<![CDATA[text]]>'`.

"contrib version" is a library version or a specific python version library (not sure exactly where difference of args num is)

Comment: Instead of commenting out those lines, I would just add `if text.startswith("<![CDATA[") and text.endswith("]]>"): return text` as the first line. That way you don't mess up non-cdata entries

Answer (score 4):

This ended up working for me in Python 2.7. Similar to Amaury's answer.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ET._original_serialize_xml = ET._serialize_xml


def _serialize_xml(write, elem, encoding, qnames, namespaces):
    if elem.tag == '![CDATA[':
        write("<%s%s]]>%s" % (elem.tag, elem.text, elem.tail))
        return
    return ET._original_serialize_xml(
         write, elem, encoding, qnames, namespaces)
ET._serialize_xml = ET._serialize['xml'] = _serialize_xml
```

Answer (score 3):

for python3 and ElementTree you can use next reciept

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ET._original_serialize_xml = ET._serialize_xml


def serialize_xml_with_CDATA(write, elem, qnames, namespaces, short_empty_elements, **kwargs):
    if elem.tag == 'CDATA':
        write("<![CDATA[{}]]>".format(elem.text))
        return
    return ET._original_serialize_xml(write, elem, qnames, namespaces, short_empty_elements, **kwargs)


ET._serialize_xml = ET._serialize['xml'] = serialize_xml_with_CDATA


def CDATA(text):
   element =  ET.Element("CDATA")
   element.text = text
   return element


my_xml = ET.Element("my_name")
my_xml.append(CDATA("<p>some text</p>")

tree = ElementTree(my_xml)
```

if you need xml as str, you can use

```
ET.tostring(tree)
```

or next hack (which almost same as code inside `tostring()`)

```
fake_file = BytesIO()
tree.write(fake_file, encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)
result_xml_text = str(fake_file.getvalue(), encoding="utf-8")
```

and get result

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<my_name>
  <![CDATA[<p>some text</p>]]>
</my_name>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered a hack to get CDATA to work using comments:

```
node.append(etree.Comment(' --><![CDATA[' + data.replace(']]>', ']]]]><![CDATA[>') + ']]><!-- '))
```

Answer (score 1):

The DOM has (atleast in level 2) an interface
DATASection, and an operation Document::createCDATASection.  They are
extension interfaces, supported only if an implementation supports the
"xml" feature.

from xml.dom import minidom

my_xmldoc=minidom.parse(xmlfile)

my_xmldoc.createCDATASection(data)

now u have cadata node add it wherever u want....

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution cannot work with **Python 2.7**. However, there is another package called [lxml](http://lxml.de/) which (though slightly slower) shared a largely identical syntax with the `xml.etree.ElementTree`. `lxml` is able to both write and parse `CDATA`. Documentation [here](http://lxml.de/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version which is based on both gooli's and amaury's answers above.  It works for both ElementTree 1.2.6 and 1.3.0, which use very different methods of doing this.

Note that gooli's does not work with 1.3.0, which seems to be the current standard in Python 2.7.x.

Also note that this version does not use the CDATA() method gooli used either.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

class ElementTreeCDATA(ET.ElementTree):
    """Subclass of ElementTree which handles CDATA blocks reasonably"""

    def _write(self, file, node, encoding, namespaces):
        """This method is for ElementTree <= 1.2.6"""

        if node.tag == '![CDATA[':
            text = node.text.encode(encoding)
            file.write("\n<![CDATA[%s]]>\n" % text)
        else:
            ET.ElementTree._write(self, file, node, encoding, namespaces)

    def _serialize_xml(write, elem, qnames, namespaces):
        """This method is for ElementTree >= 1.3.0"""

        if elem.tag == '![CDATA[':
            write("\n<![CDATA[%s]]>\n" % elem.text)
        else:
            ET._serialize_xml(write, elem, qnames, namespaces)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got here looking for a way to "parse an XML with CDATA sections and then output it again with the CDATA sections".

I was able to do this (maybe lxml has been updated since this post?) with the following: (it is a little rough - sorry ;-). Someone else may have a better way to find the CDATA sections programatically but I was too lazy.

```py
 parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8') # my original xml was utf-8 and that was a lot of the problem
 tree = etree.parse(ppath, parser)

 for cdat in tree.findall('./ProjectXMPMetadata'): # the tag where my CDATA lives
   cdat.text = etree.CDATA(cdat.text)

 # other stuff here

 tree.write(opath, encoding="UTF-8",)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Simple way of making .xml file with CDATA sections

The main idea is that we covert the element tree to a string and call [unescape](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.sax.utils.html#xml.sax.saxutils.unescape) on it. Once we have the string we use standard python to write a string to a file.

Based on:
[How to write unescaped string to a XML element with ElementTree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53691955/how-to-write-unescaped-string-to-a-xml-element-with-elementtree)

### Code that generates the XML file

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.sax.saxutils import unescape

# defining the tree structure
element1 = ET.Element('test1')
element1.text = '<![CDATA[Wired & Forbidden]]>'

# & and <> are in a weird format
string1 = ET.tostring(element1).decode()
print(string1)

# now they are not weird anymore
# more formally, we unescape '&amp;', '&lt;', and '&gt;' in a string of data
# from https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.sax.utils.html#xml.sax.saxutils.unescape
string1 = unescape(string1)
print(string1)

element2 = ET.Element('test2')
element2.text = '<![CDATA[Wired & Forbidden]]>'
string2 = unescape(ET.tostring(element2).decode())
print(string2)

# make the xml file and open in append mode
with open('foo.xml', 'a') as f:
    f.write(string1 + '\n')
    f.write(string2)
```

### Output foo.xml

```
<test1><![CDATA[Wired & Forbidden]]></test1>
<test2><![CDATA[Wired & Forbidden]]></test2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine with unescape https://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingXml is very easy solution.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import xml.dom.minidom
from xml.sax.saxutils import unescape

m_encoding = 'UTF-8'

class Xml():

def generate(self, xmlstring):        
    root = ET.Element('info')
    ET.SubElement(root, "foo").text = "<![CDATA[{}]]>".format(xmlstring)
    
    dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(root))
    xml_string = dom.toprettyxml()
    part1, part2 = xml_string.split('?>')
    
    with open(f"xmls/file.xml", 'w', encoding="UTF-8") as xfile:
        file_parts = part1 + 'encoding=\"{}\" standalone="yes"?>'.format(m_encoding) + part2
        xfile.write(unescape(file_parts, {"&apos;": "'", "&quot;": '"'}))
        xfile.close()
```