# SQL Server XML output with CDATA

Tags: sql-server, xml, cdata

Is there a way to have an SQL Server XML return use CDATA? I have XML being returned by SQL Server like this:

```
<locations>
    <site id="124">
        <sitename>Texas A &amp; M</sitename>
    </site>
</locations>
```

When I am required to have this:

```
<locations>
    <site id="124">
        <sitename><![CDATA[Texas A & M]]></sitename>
    </site>
</locations>
```

Comment: Seems like an odd requirement: they should both come to the same thing in any standards-compliant xml parser.  But then, customers will be customers.

Comment: Unfortunately, post process is not an option, as SQL has already taken column data (Texas A & M) and escaped it for XML (Texas A &amp; M) direct. Something that CDATA allows. The client doesn't want to parse the XML, then search and rewrite values. And I've quickly discovered that returning XML, rather than taking a query return and building the XML string by hand, is the definite preference.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look at the options of [FOR XML EXPLICIT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189068.aspx) (parameter *Directive*). It gives the greater degree of control and you can also specify CDATA. Here is [a good tutorial](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/jacob/archive/2007/10/14/for-xml-explicit-tutorial-part-1.aspx).

And the code addapted from that tutorial:

```sql
declare @agent table
(    
    AgentID int,
    Fname varchar(5),
    SSN varchar(11)
)

insert into @agent
select 1, 'Vimal', '123-23-4521' union all
select 2, 'Jacob', '321-52-4562' union all
select 3, 'Tom', '252-52-4563'

SELECT
    1 AS Tag,
    NULL AS Parent,
    NULL AS 'Agents!1!',
    NULL AS 'Agent!2!AgentID',
    NULL AS 'Agent!2!Fname!Element',
    NULL AS 'Agent!2!SSN!cdata'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    2 AS Tag,
    1 AS Parent,
    NULL, 
    AgentID,
    Fname,
    SSN
FROM @agent
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

Comment: Beware, though, that if you insert this output into a T-SQL XML variable or an XML field, the CDATA will be converted back to the ampersand-escaped format, and that cannot be turned off. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9133622/864696

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of my way of getting CDATA:

```
DECLARE @GlobalDateFormat varchar(32)
SET @GlobalDateFormat = 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt'

DECLARE @xml XML

SET @xml = 
(
    SELECT
            SegmentId         = ISNULL(SegmentId,0)
        ,   DocumentId        = ISNULL(DocumentId,0)
        ,   Title             = CAST(Core.dbo.fCharFormat('xmlCDATA',Title,DEFAULT,'') AS xml)
        ,   DocumentShortName = CAST(Core.dbo.fCharFormat('xmlCDATA',DocumentShortName,DEFAULT,'') AS xml)
        ,   [FileName]        = CAST(Core.dbo.fCharFormat('xmlCDATA',[FileName],DEFAULT,'') AS xml)
        ,   [Path]            = CAST(Core.dbo.fCharFormat('xmlCDATA',[Path],DEFAULT,'') AS xml)
        ,   CreateDate        = ISNULL(Core.dbo.fDateFormat(@GlobalDateFormat,CreateDate),Core.dbo.fDateFormat(@GlobalDateFormat,GETDATE()))
        ,   ModificationDate  = ISNULL(Core.dbo.fDateFormat(@GlobalDateFormat,ModificationDate),Core.dbo.fDateFormat(@GlobalDateFormat,GETDATE()))
        ,   TemplateId        = ISNULL(CAST(TemplateId AS varchar(16)),'')
        ,   IsRoot            = ISNULL(IsRoot,0)
        ,   IsActive          = ISNULL(IsActive,0)
        ,   SortOrdinal       = ISNULL(CAST(SortOrdinal AS varchar(16)),'')
        ,   ClientId          = ISNULL(ClientId,'')
        ,   Tag               = CAST(Core.dbo.fCharFormat('xmlCDATA',Tag,DEFAULT,'') AS xml)
        FROM
            Document
        WHERE
            DocumentId = 9073
        FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
)

SELECT @xml
```

Here is the relevant detail from my weasel-like, CDATA-handling function:

```
IF @cmdName = 'xmlCDATA'
BEGIN
    IF @chars IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @charsOut = @charsDefault
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @chars = REPLACE(@chars,'<![CDATA[','')
        SET @chars = REPLACE(@chars,']]>','')
        SET @charsOut = '<![CDATA[' + @chars + ']]>'
    END
END
```

Comment: This will fail if any of your data, eg. Title, contains the string `]]>`.

Comment: Ouch! Right! I am going to have to write a function devoted exclusively to CDATA... should have it by end of day...

Comment: Wait a sec' Greg, I just tried this in Management Studio:

SELECT CAST('<![CDATA[will ]] this fail?]]>' AS xml)

Have you tried this? What happens?

Comment: Nevertheless, my answer does not help the question. Now I see that that Steve Cutter is looking for CDATA markup to be preserved in output.

Comment: Try `<![CDATA[will ]]> this fail?]]>`.

Comment: @Greg you are right! This is the error: `no ']]>' in element content`. So I am going to have to write that function.

Comment: Actually, I better just frickin' learn FOR EXPLICIT syntax---just like I have to learn explicit JOIN syntax.

Comment: And developers (myself included) should stop finding them self unique and reinvent the wheel every time, we think no one else ever had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Joel mentioned in the comment above, those two forms should mean exactly the same thing. However, if the CDATA form is really required, then you could write a post-processor that takes the first form as input and outputs the second form using CDATA.

When doing this, a post-processor would *unencode* the XML-escaped data in the first form, and  re-encode it using a CDATA-compatible method. See the question [Is there a way to escape a CDATA end token in xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223652/is-there-a-way-to-escape-a-cdata-end-token-in-xml) for considerations regarding CDATA escaping.