# SQL Server XML output with CDATA into xml variable

Tags: sql-server, xml, cdata

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429351/sql-server-xml-output-with-cdata), I need to put the select result into a xml variable. How to do this avoiding the error message "The FOR XML and FOR JSON clauses are invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, and subqueries when they contain a set operator. To work around, wrap the SELECT containing a set operator using derived table or common table expression or view and apply FOR XML or FOR JSON on top of it.", please?

Here the test code:

```
declare @agent table
(    
    AgentID int,
    Fname varchar(5),
    SSN varchar(11)
)

insert into @agent
select 1, 'Vimal', '123-23-4521' union all
select 2, 'Jacob', '321-52-4562' union all
select 3, 'Tom', '252-52-4563'

SELECT
    1 AS Tag,
    NULL AS Parent,
    NULL AS 'Agents!1!',
    NULL AS 'Agent!2!AgentID',
    NULL AS 'Agent!2!Fname!Element',
    NULL AS 'Agent!2!SSN!cdata'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    2 AS Tag,
    1 AS Parent,
    NULL, 
    AgentID,
    Fname,
    SSN
FROM @agent
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

And here an example of what I want to do:

```
Declare @xml xml
...
set @xml= (SELECT
    1 AS Tag,
    NULL AS Parent,
    NULL AS 'Agents!1!',
    NULL AS 'Agent!2!AgentID',
    NULL AS 'Agent!2!Fname!Element',
    NULL AS 'Agent!2!SSN!cdata'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    2 AS Tag,
    1 AS Parent,
    NULL, 
    AgentID,
    Fname,
    SSN
FROM @agent
FOR XML EXPLICIT)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky...

You can move the `UNION ALL` part to a `CTE` like here. The problem is not the `FOR XML` but rahter the `UNION` (be carefull, it might be necessary to add an `ORDER BY` clause):

```
DECLARE @xml XML;

WITH UnionAllCte AS
(
    SELECT
        1 AS Tag,
        NULL AS Parent,
        NULL AS 'Agents!1!',
        NULL AS 'Agent!2!AgentID',
        NULL AS 'Agent!2!Fname!Element',
        NULL AS 'Agent!2!SSN!cdata'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        2 AS Tag,
        1 AS Parent,
        NULL, 
        AgentID,
        Fname,
        SSN
    FROM @agent
)
SELECT @xml=
(
    SELECT * FROM UnionAllCte
    FOR XML EXPLICIT
)

SELECT @xml;
```

And you should be aware, that `CDATA` as well as `FOR XML EXPLICIT` are outdated. Rather use `FOR XML PATH()` and for reading the appropriate [methods the XML data type provides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx).

You [might read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39485752/5089204) and read the following links too!