# JAXB - unmarshall element which contains a HTML page

Tags: java, javascript, jaxb

I use JavaScript to send a page source code (`document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML`) to my web service in element `<pagesource>...</pagesource>`. Obviously there are HTML tags in there and because of it I get an error during unmarshalling. Is it possible to somehow parse this or escape all bad characters?

`ERROR`

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 52; columnNumber: 3; The element type "input" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</input>".]
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:335)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:514)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:215)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:184)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
at cz.fit.cvut.swe.pagerating.ws.WebService.addRating(WebService.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:43)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:249)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:391)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:160)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 52; columnNumber: 3; The element type "input" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</input>".
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:391)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1391)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1726)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2915)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:625)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:821)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:750)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1208)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:525)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:211)
... 48 more
```

Comment: You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery) usefull for escaping html

Comment: @Radu And if I don't want to use jQuery , can it be done  on the server side?

Comment: If you have an intermediate module between the js and the web service invocation, you could also try doing this in [java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java)

Comment: it's kind of too late on the server side, you already have a broken xml document.  you need to escape it _before_ you put it in the xml document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you construct the XML that gets sent to the server, you could just surround the HTML with `<![CDATA[ ]]>`. The HTML will then be parsed as a string by the parser on the server.

e.g.

```
<pagesource><![CDATA[<html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>]]></pagesource>
```

Comment: This does not work - throws `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 33; columnNumber: 158; Content is not allowed in trailing section.`

Comment: @Tom The usage of <![CDATA[]]> should work. You can try testing you WebService with [soapUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/) using a dummy request that contains <![CDATA[]]>. Based on the results you get, you should be able to build a similar message in js.

Comment: @DanielBell You're right. It's working. I probably had a wrong page because I discovered that the source code is not from the page but from the chrome extension I use for sending it. I had to send only the URL and get the source code in the web service.

Comment: @DanielBell I found a problem with this solution. If I want to parse a page which has `]]>` somewhere in it, it closes my CDATA tag and causes an error. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to escape the CDATA end token (]]>). There are some workarounds here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223652/is-there-a-way-to-escape-a-cdata-end-token-in-xml