# How to unmarshal an XML containing a CDATA section within a CDATA in Java?

Tags: java, xml, cdata, unmarshalling

I have an XMl containing a CDATA section containing a nested CDATA section. How is the unmarshalling supposed to be done in this case. Is this possible in Java?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A simple example document would be helpful in understanding your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to unmarshal such a document, because the document is invalid.  For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<foo>
  <bar><![CDATA[This should contain a nested cdata, which <![CDATA[Contains another CDATA]]>]]></bar>
</foo>
```

Fails to parse because the character sequence `]]>` can only be used to mark the end of a `CDATA` section.  In a nutshell, you can't nest `CDATA` sections.  You'll have to figure out another approach.

See the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#Nesting), and [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123864/nesting-xml-cdata-into-a-xml-file) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

JAXB framework is what you are looking for. 
JAXB stands for Java Architecture for XML Binding.

```
JAXB object has the capability of Marshaling and UnMarshaling.
```

It is not complex. Go for it :)

In context of your question,

You can do it by having multilevel class structure.
For Eg:

Suppose you have two classes :

```
class A
{
  (@xmlName : CDATA1)
  B obj;
}

class B
{
  (@xmlName : CDATA2)
  String string;
}
```

Here when you unmarshal in context of object of class A.

The inner CDATA would land up in the `string` member of `obj`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know about JAXB, but the real question is whether it is possible to unmarshall an XML containing a CDATA within a CDATA. With SAXParser, i'm unable to do so as it fails on nested CDATA :(

Comment: Sameer : Thanks for your prompt reply. Even with this, the SAXBuilder throws an exception while building the Document itself using the build() on SAXBuilder.

Comment: @VipinPillai - Can you post the exception you are seeing?