# VisualStudio can't recognize my snippets when the code uses html tags

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, code-snippets

When I use "**< a > < ! [ CDATA[]]> < / a >.Value**" anywhere in my code and then I try to export and later import as Snippet then VisualStudio can't recognize the snippet because the tags are in confliction.

For example in this variable I use the tags:

```
Dim RegEx As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex( _
<a><![CDATA[(http://|https://|www).*\.html?]]></a>.Value)
```

...So I can put it in a .Snippet file but I can't use it 'cause the tags are in confliction with the other tags of the snippet file so VS can't recognize the snippet file.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**How I can resolve this?**

PS: Is not a solution for me to use double-quotes **""** instead "**< a > < ! [CDATA[ ]] > < / a >.Value**"

This is a sample snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
      <Title>
         Regex match htm html
      </Title>
      <Author>Elektro H@cker</Author>
      <Description>
         Expresión regular para encontrar urls.htm
      </Description>
      <HelpUrl>
      </HelpUrl>
      <Shortcut>
      </Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>aaaaaaaaa</ID>
          <ToolTip>sfsdf</ToolTip>
          <Default>
          </Default>
          <Function>sdfsdf</Function>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="vb"><![CDATA[

#Region " RegEx Match htm-html "

    ' [ RegEx Match htm-html Function ]
    '
    ' // By Elektro H@cker
    '
    ' Examples :
    ' Dim str As String = <a><![CDATA[href="http://www.mp3crank.com/the-rolling-stones/deluxe-edition.htm"]]></a>.Value
    ' MsgBox(RegEx_Match_htm_html(str)) ' Result: http://www.mp3crank.com/the-rolling-stones/deluxe-edition.htm

    Private Function RegEx_Match_htm_html(ByVal str As String, Optional ByVal Group As Int32 = 0) As String

        ' Match criteria:
        '
        ' http://text.htm
        ' http://text.html
        ' https://text.htm
        ' https://text.html
        ' www.text.htm
        ' www.text.html

        Dim RegEx As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex( _
        <a><![CDATA[(http://|https://|www).*\.html?]]></a>.Value)

        Return RegEx.Match(Str).Groups(Group).ToString

    End Function

#End Region

]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Comment: You can't put a CDATA end char in a CDATA...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to escape a CDATA end token in xml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223652/is-there-a-way-to-escape-a-cdata-end-token-in-xml)

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance sorry but I don't understanded anything, the code works perfectly outside the snippet, just of course I can notice the CDATA is in confliction with the other tags in the snippet, but I don't know html language so I don't understanded what you said and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: @dtb I've read that "solution" and I still having the same problem, I don't understand how to resolve the problem doing the modifications in the snippet file.

Comment: Your .snippet file is an XML file. In that XML file is a <Code> element which contains a CDATA node. *Inside* that CDATA node you can write whatever you want – except the sequence `]]>`. But that's what you do. Solution: don't do that.

Comment: @dtb "Solution: don't do that.", that's not a solution, please can you tell me what can I do or if I cant?

Comment: Try making it a literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the CDATA end tag a literal. 
Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
      <Title>
         Regex match htm html
      </Title>
      <Author>Elektro H@cker</Author>
      <Description>
         Expresión regular para encontrar urls.htm
      </Description>
      <HelpUrl>
      </HelpUrl>
      <Shortcut>
      </Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>aaaaaaaaa</ID>
          <ToolTip>sfsdf</ToolTip>
          <Default>
          </Default>
          <Function>sdfsdf</Function>
        </Literal>
        <Literal Editable="false">
          <ID>cdataend</ID>
          <ToolTip>Part of the CDATA end tag.</ToolTip>
          <Default>&gt;</Default>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="vb"><![CDATA[

#Region " RegEx Match htm-html "

    ' [ RegEx Match htm-html Function ]
    '
    ' // By Elektro H@cker
    '
    ' Examples :
    ' Dim str As String = <a><![CDATA[href="http://www.mp3crank.com/the-rolling-stones/deluxe-edition.htm"]]$cdataend$</a>.Value
    ' MsgBox(RegEx_Match_htm_html(str)) ' Result: http://www.mp3crank.com/the-rolling-stones/deluxe-edition.htm

    Private Function RegEx_Match_htm_html(ByVal str As String, Optional ByVal Group As Int32 = 0) As String

        ' Match criteria:
        '
        ' http://text.htm
        ' http://text.html
        ' https://text.htm
        ' https://text.html
        ' www.text.htm
        ' www.text.html

        Dim RegEx As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex( _
        <a><![CDATA[(http://|https://|www).*\.html?]]$cdataend$</a>.Value)

        Return RegEx.Match(Str).Groups(Group).ToString

    End Function

#End Region

]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Should now work.

Comment: I've tested this with a C# snippet. Add a snippet shortcut, then it should be visible.

Comment: my bad the IDE shows the snippet title attribute and not the filename, it works perfectly, you're great, thankyou so much for your time!