# Lua multiline comments past ]]'s

Tags: lua, comments, multiline

I'm trying to find out a way to use a multiline comment on a batch of code, but it keeps mistaking some syntax in it as a ]] and thinking I want it to end there, which I don't!

```
--[[
  for k,v in pairs(t) do
    local d = fullToShort[k]
    local col = xColours[v[1]] -- It stops here!
    cecho(string.format(("<%s>%s ", col, d))
  end
--]]
```

I thought I read somewhere it was possible to do use a different sort of combination to avoid those errors, like --[=[ or whatnot... Could someone help?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

As you can see in [Strings tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringsTutorial) there is a special `[===[` syntax for nesting square braces. You can use it in block comments too. Just note, that number of `=` signs must be the same in open and close sequence.

For example 5 equals will work.

```lua
--[=====[ 
for k,v in pairs(t) do
   local d = fullToShort[k]
   local col = xColours[v[1]] -- It stops here!
   cecho(string.format(("<%s>%s ", col, d))
end
--]=====]
```

Comment: That almost feels like a kludge. I wonder why they did it that way?

Comment: @James That's not a kludge - that's the only *right* way to do it. Every other fixed "magic comment closing character sequence" (henceforth MCCCS) fundamentally cannot cope with strings that contain the MCCCS itself. That's why you end up with [atrocities like `]]]]><![CDATA[>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/223782/2707792) every single time you want to write `]]>` in `CDATA`. The only way to avoid it is to provide paired delimiters that can vary in length (or content, as in bash HEREDOCs). A much better question would have been: why don't all the other languages do it like Lua?

Comment: Cool, it also works when inserting a multine string between `[[` and `]]` inside a block comment. In this case, you can also put the `=` in the embedded block to distinguish it from the containing block boundaries, e.g. using `[=[` and `]=]`

Comment: @AndreyTyukin OCaml solves the issue in an elegant way: comments must contain valid code tokens: `(* "*)" *)` works as well as `(* … (* nested comment *) ... *)`. It allows you to comment _any_ piece of syntaxically-valid code with no issue.

Comment: The link seems to be outdated.

Comment: @tsilvs the whole wiki seems to be dead, but still refered in oficial website and other places. I'll keep an eye on it if it resurfaces.
There is a more dry explanation in oficial reference (see end of paragraph, and the definition of "opening long bracket" https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.1

Answer (score -4):

You can use the following to create multiline comments past `]]`'s:

```
--[[
   codes
]]
```

Comment: The answer reflects the question title. I am fine with that. What would be good to do is to rewrite original question title.

Comment: I don't see any `]]`'s in the comment.