# How to display ]]> in CDATA

Tags: xml, cdata

How can I display a string like ]]> in XML ? I tried using normal XML and CDATA, but in XML it doesn't show anything while in CDATA it gives an error.

Comment: [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/223773/1624318)