# Elementtree and Unicode or UTF-8 confusion

Tags: python, xml, unicode, utf-8

Okay, I feel a bit lost right now. I have some problems with unicode (or utf-8 ?)

I am using Python3.3 on linux (But I have the same problem on windows).

I try to create an XML file with Elementtree.

```
    item = ET.Element("item")
    item_title = Et.SubElement(item, "title")
```

That is of course not everything, just an example.
So now I want to have the tag 'title' have a text like this (replace the ##Content## with random content, doesnt matter so much):

```
    # Thats how I create the text for the tag
    item.title.text = u'<![CDATA[##CONTENT##]>'

    # This is how I want it to look like
    <title><![CDATA[##CONTENT##]></title>

    # Thats what I get
    <title>&lt;![CDATA[##CONTENT##]&gt;</title>

    # These are some of the things I tried for writing it to an xml file
    ET.ElementTree(item).write(myOutputFile, encoding="unicode")
    myOutputFile.write(ET.tostring(item, encoding='unicode', method='xml')))
    myOutputFile.write(str(ET.tostring(item, encoding='utf-8', method='xml'))) 
    myOutputFile.write(str(ET.tostring(item)

    # Oh and thats how I open the file for writing
    myOutputFile = codecs.open(HereIsMyFile, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
```

I tried to search and found some similar sounding problems (some of the things I tried are from SO already), but none seems to work. They changed some stuff in the output, but never showed the < or >.
I also noticed, if I use utf-8 I have to use str() when writing to the file. That got me also confused about the difference in unicode and utf-8, I tried to read some stuff about that but that didn't really help me in my actual problem.

At this point I don't really know where to look for my error and I would love a hint where to look. 
Is it the way I write to the file? How I open it?
Or is it Elementtree causing the error? (I didn't try something else, like lxml, because well, that would mean rewriting a lot of stuff I guess).

I hope you can help me and if something isn't clear I will try to explain it a bit better!

Edit: Oh and I also tried to open the file without codecs, because I somewhere read it is not needed anymore in Python3.x but I wasn't so sure anymore, so I tried it.

Comment: 1. What error do you get?

Comment: If you are referencing to "Or is it Elementtree causing the error", I have to correct myself maybe, I don't get an actual error from python, but the output in the file is not how I want it to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The correct way to write an XML document with ElementTree is:

   with codecs.open(HereIsMyFile, 'w', encoding='utf-8'):
          root.write(myOutputFile)
2. If you specify an encoding for `write()`, you must use [what the XML standard defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-EncodingDecl). `unicode` isn't an encoding, it's a standard.
3. ElementTree doesn't support CDATA. The effect you're seeing is that ElementTree notices special characters in the `text` of the node and it escapes them; there is no way to prevent that.

   This answer contains the implementation of a CDATA element: [How to output CDATA using ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174890/how-to-output-cdata-using-elementtree)

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, using the solution in your link for CDATA helped solving my < > problem in a quick test!

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a couple of layers of confusion here.

Taking the lower level first: encodings such as UTF-8 convert *Unicode characters* into *bytes*. Your problem is that the characters in your generated XML aren’t the ones you want, not with how those characters are stored as bytes, so there isn’t anything to fix there.

Secondly, you seem to be expecting the wrong thing from this line:

```
item.title.text = u'<![CDATA[##CONTENT##]>'
```

This tells ElementTree that you want that text in the parsed document. Consider this:

```
item.title.text = u'I <3 ASCII art.'
```

ElementTree won’t store that directly in the markup: it’ll turn it into

```
<title>I &lt;3 ASCII art.</title>
```

Likewise:

```
item.title.text = u"This </title> isn’t the end of the title"
```

becomes

```
<title>This &lt;/title&gt; isn&#8217;t the end of the title</title>
```

Hopefully you can see the value of this: no matter what text you put in there, it won’t break the element markup, or indeed affect it in any way.

Note that because of this automatic conversion, **you very likely don’t need CDATA sections at all**.

If for some reason you do, though, you can do it by stating it explicitly (using lxml.etree):

```
title = lxml.etree.Element('title')
title.text = lxml.etree.CDATA('###CONTENT###')
print(lxml.etree.tostring(title))
```

outputs:

```
<title><![CDATA[###CONTENT###]]></title>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And sorry for the late response. I will try your solution out today, because it looks nicer than what I am using right now. Sadly I do need CDATA :( Very nice explanation, too!