# Getting the whole content within the tag including html tags

Tags: python

```
import lxml.html as PARSER
from lxml.html import fromstring

data = """<TextFormat>06</TextFormat>
<Text><![CDATA[<html><body><p>Ducdame was John Cowper Powys<p>other text</p></p></body></html>]]></Text>"""
root = PARSER.fromstring(data)

for ele in root.getiterator():
    if ele.tag == 'text':
        print ele.text_content()
```

This is what I am getting now -> Ducdame was John Cowper Powysother text.

But I need the whole content within the "Text" tag.
This is the result I am expecting.

```
<![CDATA[<html><body><p>Ducdame was John Cowper Powys<p>other text</p></p></body></html>]]>
```

I have tried lxml, BeautifulSoup but didn't got the result I am expecting.
I really need help for this one.

Thanks

Comment: It's not working, because your data is not properly encoded. You can't use strings with XML syntax elements as a string inside of XML. Encode < and > as &lt; and &gr; etc. and it will work.

Comment: Actually sir this input from .onx file format but I didn't knew how exactly I should parse it. So I tried using lxml library. 
But that’s exactly input what I am getting from my input file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example with `LXML`. In order to find the correct tags use xpath, here `.//text`:

```
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree

text = """<TextFormat>06</TextFormat>
<Text><![CDATA[<html><body><p>Ducdame was John Cowper Powys<p>other text</p></p></body>  </html>]]></Text>"""

tree = html.fromstring(text)
tags = tree.xpath('.//text')

text_tag = tags[-1]
print etree.tostring(text_tag)
```

**Output**

```
'<text><p>Ducdame was John Cowper Powys</p><p>other text</p></text>'
```

If you need `CDATA` as well you can find the following post useful: [How to output CDATA using ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174890/how-to-output-cdata-using-elementtree)

Comment: Sir if possible can you show me how to get CDATA is this example only.

Answer (score 2):

This example below work with the `minidom` module.

```
import xml.dom.minidom

data = """<Text><![CDATA[<html><body><p>Ducdame was John Cowper Powys<p>other text</p></p></body></html>]]></Text>"""

p = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(data)
p = p.childNodes[0]
p = p.childNodes[0]
print p.toxml()
```

Comment: Thanks sir this is exactly what I was expecting.
But how should I traverse to the "Text" tag. Suppose my file have two tags.
<TextTypeCode>02</TextTypeCode>
<Text><![CDATA[<html><body><p>Ducdame was John Cowper Powys<p>other text</p></p></body></html>]]></Text>"""
Then how I will reach to "<Text>" tag