# ElementTree write <> into element text

Tags: elementtree

I would like to put <> characters in element content but after write I getting &lt ; and &gt ;

```
ET.SubElement(ShipTo, "CompanyOrName").text = '<![CDATA[{}]]>'.format(address['company'])
```

effect:

```
<CompanyOrName>&lt;![CDATA[Company]]&gt;</CompanyOrName>
```

Comment: however I took the lxml, it allows you to insert CDATA

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to output CDATA using ElementTree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174890/how-to-output-cdata-using-elementtree)