# Do not strip CDATA from ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, cdata

I need to find all elements which contain CDATA. I iterate through the entire tree.
The problem is, ElementTree strips CDATA tag, leaving no trace. Is there a similar solution to nodeType or CDATASection from xml.dom?
Thanks

Comment: Here is a similar question with several answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174890/how-to-output-cdata-using-elementtree

Comment: It might not help you, but if CDATA is important to you, then CDATA is being misused. Writing `<a><![CDATA[xxx]]></a>` should be 100% equivalent to writing `<a>xxx</a>` which is why most XML APIs won't distinguish the two in the data they pass to the application.

Comment: I'm trying to fix some files. An attribute got changed to CDATA text somehow. So I need to know if it is the cdata value or not.