# How to write unescaped string to a XML element with ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have a string variable `contents` with following value:

```
<ph type="0" x="1"></ph>
```

I try to write it to a XML element as follows:

```
elemen_ref.text = contents
```

After I write XML tree to a file and check it with Notepad++, I see following value written to the XML element:

```
&lt;ph type="0" x="1"&gt;&lt;/ph&gt;
```

How do I write unescaped string? Please note that this value is copied from another XML element which remains intact after writing tree to a file, so the issue is with assigning value to a `text` attribute.

Answer (score 4):

You are  attempting to do this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element('root')
content_str = '<ph type="0" x="1"></ph>'
root.text = content_str

print(ET.tostring(root))
#  <root>&lt;ph type="0" x="1"&gt;&lt;/ph&gt;</root>
```

Which is essentially "injecting" XML to an element's text property. This is not the correct way to do this.

Instead, you should convert the `content` string to an actual XML node that can be appended to the existing XML node.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element('root')
content_str = '<ph type="0" x="1"></ph>'
content_element = ET.fromstring(content_str)
root.append(content_element)

print(ET.tostring(root))
#  <root><ph type="0" x="1" /></root>
```

If you insist, you can use [`unescape`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.sax.utils.html#xml.sax.saxutils.escape):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.sax.saxutils import unescape

root = ET.Element('root')
content_str = '<ph type="0" x="1"></ph>'
root.text = content_str

print(unescape(ET.tostring(root).decode()))
#  <root><ph type="0" x="1"></ph></root>
```

Comment: Converting `content` looked like a valid option, but it does not work with other strings of formatted text, for example:

`My test<pha type="0" />` and

`16<bpt i="1" type="25" />th<ept i="1" /> November 2018`

Comment: I am not sure about second option of unescaping whole XML either, because I'm altering a single node in ~300 MB XML document, thus I'm afraid that unescaping whole thing will make unwanted modifications.