# XML line break character entity and Python encoding

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have the following line of code in a python script:

```
dep11 = ET.SubElement(dep1, "POVCode").text = "#declare lg_quality = LDXQual;&#x0A;#if (lg_quality = 3)&#x0A;#declare lg_quality = 4;&#x0A;#end"
```

My question is in regards to the `&#x0A;` character. I want to see this character entity in the XML output, but the first ampersand keeps getting replaced with the `&amp;` character entity, which creates the nonsense character entity `&amp;#x0A;`.

I am encoding the file as `utf-8`.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

...

with open("LGEO.xml", "wb") as f:
    tree.write(f, "utf-8")
```

And I end up with:

```
<POVCode>#declare lg_quality = LDXQual;&amp;#x0A;#if (lg_quality = 3)&amp;#x0A;#declare lg_quality = 4;&amp;#x0A;#end</POVCode>
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[edit]

I am trying to implement the solution found here that @mzjn pointed out.

[How to output XML entity references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986272/how-to-output-xml-entity-references)

I have six lines of code:

```
dep11 = ET.SubElement(dep1, "POVCode")
dep21 = ET.SubElement(dep2, "POVCode")
dep11.text = "#declare lg_quality = LDXQual;&&#x0A;#if (lg_quality = 3)&&#x0A;#declare lg_quality = 4;&&#x0A;#end"
dep21.text = "#declare lg_studs = LDXStuds;&&#x0A;"
ET.tostring(dep11).replace('&amp;&amp;', '&')
ET.tostring(dep21).replace('&amp;&amp;', '&')
```

I get no error, but the result is not any different than before when I `write` the tree.

Again I am stuck.

Comment: Have you tried adding encoding declaration to the python file? (`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of the file)

Comment: I just tried that but it didn't help.

Comment: Very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7986272/407651

Comment: The issue is exactly the same. There's only the one suggestion of a solution however.

Comment: I found a solution and will post it when I get a chance.

Comment: You should add the text as a [CDATA section](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect). This is much easier in lxml, but possible in ElementTree. See this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55150569/317052

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I eventually did was use the standard Python `write` function instead of using ElementTree's own `write` function.

```
text = ET.tostring(root).replace("&amp;&amp;", "&")

with open("LGEO.xml", "wb") as f:
    f.write(text.encode("utf-8"))
```

The above is the last step in the Python code. I don't know if there are disadvantages to converting the root object to a string like this. It could be slower but it works for me.