# Construct lxml.etree from json disable excaping

Tags: python, lxml

I have a python script which takes a json and generates an xml with the values that I need. Unfortunately one of the values has CDATA tag which is escaped somehow by lxml.etree. How do I disable it?

```
import lxml.etree as ET

print ("Desired:")
print (ET.tostring(string_res, encoding='utf-8', method='xml'))
string_res.text = ''
string_res.text = value['Value']

print ("Desired:")
print string_res.text

print ("Not desired:")
print (ET.tostring(string_res, encoding='utf-8', method='xml'))
```

result is

```
Desired:
<![CDATA[<b>hello</b>]]>

Desired:
<![CDATA[<b>hello</b>]]>

Not desired:
&lt;![CDATA[&lt;b&gt;hello&lt;/b&gt;]]&gt;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174890/how-to-output-cdata-using-elementtree

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to output CDATA using ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174890/how-to-output-cdata-using-elementtree)