# How to edit and retain CDATA section with ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, cdata

I am working with an xml file which uses CDATA in some of the tags. I wish to edit the contents of CDATA but the ElementTree parser removes the CDATA from output xml

Sample input xml:

```
<question type="multichoice">
    <name>
      <text>decimal to binary 1</text>
    </name>
    <questiontext format="html">
      <text><![CDATA[<p dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">Convert the following number from decimal to binary:</p><p dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">248<sub>10</sub></p>]]></text>
    </questiontext>
    <generalfeedback format="html">
      <text></text>
    </generalfeedback>
    <defaultgrade>1.0000000</defaultgrade>
...
```

This is a part of the xml input file. I wish to edit the CDATA in the `text` tag to change the question and append this to an output xml file. How can I achieve this?

I tried some of the solutions from stackoverflow, but some of them were too convoluted to follow and didn't match my exact needs

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/174890/407651 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/55217892/407651 for example?

Comment: You can also use XSLT for your task.

Comment: Second link posted by @mzjn is the way to go: use `lxml`

Comment: Update: The cdata method of lxml.etree module is exactly what I was looking for.