# How to write HTML to XML file with xml.etree.ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

One of my subelements of my xml file has to contain a HTML code snippet eg.:

```
import import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

.
.
.

qtext = ET.SubElement(questiontext, 'text')
qtext.text = '<![CDATA[<div class="qtext"></div>]]>'
```

I define several other elements during the process. At the end I save with:

```
tree._setroot(quiz)
tree.write("quiz.xml", encoding="UTF-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

The snippet in the exported XML file looks like:

```
<text>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;div class="qtext"&gt;</text>
```

Instead of:

```
<text><![CDATA[<div class="qtext"></text>
```

I have a working XML file as a standard example. My job is to copy it's structure. This is the reason why I have to include the HTML snippet. The file will be imported into Moodle.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simple solution in a question regarded to CDATA writing in XML code.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58392720/14865752

Basically it overrides the ET._escape_cdata(text) function. Eliminating all escape characters.